# Caurina Transitions

Tags: apache-flex, import, transition, tweener

How to import it in Flex?

import caurina.transitions.Tweener;

It says: 1120: Access of undefined property Tweener.
When I do something like: Tweener.addTween(...

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to either

- copy the tweener's `SWC` to the Flex library path or
- copy the `caurina` folder to the Flex classpath or
- copy the `caurina` folder to the root folder of your source code (where main `Application` class is located)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, the problem was that my path was: "caurina/transitions/Tweener" instead of just being "caurina/transitions"